# The specified directory to the Visual Studio extension either does not exist

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I just created CordovaApp (Multi-Device Hybrid App) in VS 2013. The application was working fine. Then I tried to open app with VS 2015 Community edition in another machine (and on same machine) and I am receiving following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The specified directory to the Visual Studio extension
>   D:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\node.exe either does not exist, or does not contain a packages\vs-mda sub-directory. Please
>   check that the extension directory exists and set the MDAVsixDir
>   variable to the correct
>   directory.    MyAppCordovaApp C:\Users\foouser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets  105

I also installed Cordova Tools for VS update 6.

Is there any known work-around for this issue?

Comment: If you create a new, Blank, Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015, are you able to run that application without errors?

Comment: It was an almost brand new application (just few lines of code) -- Anyway, after long hours of frustration, I decided to get Xamarin subscription and develop on that environment. I will just keep question open due to some one else would have similar issue and may suggest some resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Cordova project created in VS2013 is not going to run/debug at VS2015.

NodeJS module used for building the project is no longer called vs-mda (i.e. Visual Studio Multi-Device Application) but vs-tac (i.e. Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova).

After perform manual migration, it is working now.

See reference:-
http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/07/31/migrating-a-cordova-project-from-visual-studio-2013-to-visual-studio-2015/